# Posting values for multiple radio groups to spring controller

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I have multiple radio groups and with its corresponding selections. When I select a particular option for a particular group, I would like to post the value for that particular selection to the controller mapping when I do a submit. 
I have done that using a request parameter for a single radio group, but if I would like to get the values for multiple radio groups in the form of an array. Can you tell me how do I do that?
An example of the HTML code below

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="somevalue"> 
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="somevalue"> 
<input type="radio" name="group3" value="somevalue">
```

Spring controller side,I would like all radio group values in the form of an array

```
@RequestParam(value="group1,group2,group3") String[] Array_of_all_radio_group_values
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the radio groups with it name as array in the controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/postFormData", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public void saveFormDataMethod(@RequestParam("group1") String[] group1,
                               @RequestParam("group2") String[] group2,
                               @RequestParam("group3") String[] group3){

      //access the checked option values here
      System.out.println("Checked Group1 Elements :"+Arrays.toString(group1));

}
```